# When I boot, I get a GRUB boot error: no such device, and then grub rescue> what should i do?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grubrescue

I've just installed Ubuntu on my external HDD, during the installation it also installed GRUB boot loader since I’m also running windows 7 on my internal HDD. After the I installation though, I got a GRUB boot error:

```
error: no such device: 54c36c16-b07e-40d3-9fe6-0bbb47a418bd
entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> _
```

I've already read several other tips and instructions on  other forums that told me to enter the following code:

```
set root=(hd0, msdos2)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

I tried this with all of my listed partitions but every time I enter `"insmod normal"` it gives me an "unknown file system". What should I do?

Comment: Try boot-repair.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering my own question??)

My GRUB was out of date, so I simply created a boot recovery live USB drive with "Boot Repair" and suddenly everything was back to normal!!